# eZ430-Chronos Development on *nix?

Tags: linux, microcontroller

So I just got my **TI eZ430-Chronos** Dev kit (a runners watch & eZ430 micro dev combined), and I am chomping at the bit to start playing around with my new toy. I have just a few issues the recommended tools from TI are Windows based, and I am lacking a valid windows OS right now.  Also I brought the watch back to work, but left the programmer and AP at home.  So I am left reading articles and links to wiki's, but unable to try anything out for myself.

Stuff I have read so far:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8682
http://wiki.msp430.com/index.php/EZ430-Chronos
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc4
http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/01/ti_ez430_-_chronos_development_kit.html

I also searched the mspgcc sf mailing-list, it had no mention of the chronos.

Has anyone been able to get mspgcc or mspgcc4 to work with the Chronos. I have searched for 
information about this on the various sites, but found no answers.  It should be very straight forward, but I will give it a shot later and report back if I don't hear back.

Comment: http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/ez430-chronos.html

Comment: In the comments section of the Make:Blog link there's reference to geting it working using XP in VirtualBox under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out mspdebug it should get your code onto the device and do some debugging there. I also saw that someone patched mspgcc v3.2.3 to handle the cc430 in the chronos.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine yesterday. They have only just started shipping them in quantity (I know several people who have just got them), so I think it will be some time before anyone has a go at porting the software to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The Rowley crossworks toolset is a very high performance development system for the MSP430.  It is available for Linux, MAC OS-X and Solaris as well as Windows.  It is not free, prices according to license type:

$1500 — Commercial License

$300 — Educational License

$150 — Personal License

This supports both the 430 and 430X (larger memory) architectures.  IIRC the GCC port only supports the 430.

Comment: The GCC port supports the 430X variant in the cvs version.  Regular msp430 support is more mature, of course.

Comment: I am not an MSPGCC user so I can only go from what I pick up from the chatter on the yahoo MSP group.  From a quick look at the sourceforge user forum for MSPGCC there are still issues with the large memory devices.  It is not as seamless as the IAR and Rowley offerings.

Answer (score 1):

Several people are using mspgcc4 including me. I'm the rare type in that I used it in XP (work machine) and haven't actually tried Linux. I have some 430's and I'm waiting to see if they'll ever ship me a Launchpad so I expect I'll get back to the arch sometime in near future.

Either way, have a look at the non-dead, uncrippled, and not broken_on_half_the_compilers_advertised [Openchronos](http://github.com/poelzi/OpenChronos) and #openchronos on freenode. All these people are using GCC4 on the Chronos kit.

Comment: The basestation works quite easily, btw. I even wrote some application using mingw on Debian that ran in Wine that could be dropped to a windows host with no changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is the control panel and sample code software available for Linux for download from TI. I'm not going to look it up but you can. I installed it but was having a problem with it seeing the USB adapter. It does run and like I said it was the adapter driver that was the issue. I'm not a Linux guru but I can I was able to get it going just never bothered to finish up with the USB problem.

Answer (score 1):

here you can find instructions on how to install the latest mspgcc (as of 06/12/2011)

https://github.com/sergiocampama/Launchpad/blob/master/README.md

i am 99% sure that the cc430 is supported in this version, and mspdebug should be able to install it, so the chronos should be supported..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically what you need, WINE might help you somewhat, but if you need access to USB ports etc then you may be stuck (I had a similar problem whereMPLAB appears to function properly under WINE but can't access the USB port - but for PICs there are Linux alternatives).

Hopefully when you get home you'll be able to check if you can connect to the device from the command line etc, as mspgcc etc appear to work under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just got started with EZ430 Chronos hacking, but it seems that on a contemporary Debian, all the tools you need are easily available:

```
apt-get install mspdebug gcc-msp430
git clone git@gitorious.org:openchronos/openchronos.git OpenChronos
cd OpenChronos
make config && make
mspdebug rf2500 prog\ build/eZChronos.txt
```